# How would you calculate final velocity for the simple electric train experiment?

Tags: electromagnetism, propulsion

Alright, so basically I have an experiment to make, which is similar to the simple train video on youtube. I want to test different voltages & gauges of copper wire to see the changes in velocity. I want to be able to hypothesize the final velocities of each of the different experiments, so looking at the video, how would you be able to calculate the final velocity for the battery? I am a grade 12 student from a high school in Ontario.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9b0J29OzAU&t=24s

Here is the video, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw it's not technically a train unless there is more than one towed car.

I think you will find that the finaly velocity of the car is proportional to the strength of the solenoid B field. If you look up solenoids you will find this is given by

$$v_f\propto B=\mu_0 \frac{NV}{lR}$$

$v_f$ final velocity

$B$ solenoidal B field

$\mu_0$ is the permeability of space, which equals $4\pi\times10^{-7}$ Tm/A

$N$ is the number of turns of the solenoid from one end of the car to the other

$l$ is the length of the part of wire from one end of the car to the other

$V$ is the battery voltage

$R$ is the wire resistance

Any changes to friction or strength of the car magnets, or of course gravitational gradient, will also alter the resulting velocity.

That should get you started.

Comment: solenoidal B field <-- What would this be, the electromagnetic field? Would it be in mT and What device will I use to measure it? One last thing, Is there a name for this equation?